# How can I know if an unranked IEEE conference is good or bad?

Tags: conference, ieee, ranking

I have seen IEEE conferences having A-C ranks in the conference ranks website but I cant find the rank of this conference [IEEE INCET](http://www.incet.org/). Although all the proceedings are published to IEEE Xplore I was concerned about the rank and quality. I’ve heard that it’s actually a red flag when you publish to unranked/ bad conferences and you shouldn’t add these to your CV. Can anyone enlighten me about this specific conference as I’ve a paper there? Apologies if this is repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

IEEE watches for minimum quality of all the conferences it sponsors and will for example not accept papers for publication in IEEE Explore automatically. It is also pretty good at preventing predatory conferences, where people pay to publish, by watching over the paper acceptance process.

IEEE also realizes that for people from poorer countries, like India, travel to Europe or the US, where the majority of class A conferences are located, is difficult and is therefore quite generous to conference organizers from South Asia or Africa to organize conferences of more local impact.

In general, there is no reason to not list a paper at an IEEE sponsored conference on your CV. The advise about bad conferences is for predatory conferences, where the listing admits either that you are a cheat (you knowingly pay for a scientific publication without proper refereeing), or a flat (you believed the organizers of a predatory conference).

Besides being sponsored by IEEE, you also look for publication in IEEEXplore. If IEEE does not trust the quality of the conference, they will not automatically accept presented papers for IEEEXplore submission. This only means that there is one more step of IEEE quality control to be passed.

Second, you look at the technical programming committee. In general, you want people from a variety of places and not of the same background. You can take a sample and look at the qualifications and the publication record of the members.

Third, you can look at the acceptance / rejection rate of previous conferences. Acceptance rates under 50% will make the conference selective.

You can also look at indexing of the conference proceedings by e.g. Scopus or where papers are getting published (e.g. Springer Lecture Notes) as a positive sign. Whether this will do you any good for promotion will still depend on how criteria are evaluated, since there is still a prejudice against conferences.

You should also include the possibility of networking and the costs in your decision making process. For example, if you have a relatively weak, but not predatory local conference, it might still be worth while to make a weaker aspect of your work or a summary of published work with a new twist into a paper to submit there and then attend in person.

Comment: *IEEE watches for minimum quality* yes, sure:
 https://retractionwatch.com/2023/06/15/plague-of-anomalies-in-conference-proceedings-hint-at-systemic-issues/

Comment: I was just wanting to know if the conference I mentioned is a bad / predatory conference or not since its unranked

Comment: Use my criteria while looking at their web-site. I did it, but I will not do the evaluation for you.

Comment: EarlGrey: Yes, sometimes things slip by. Usually the culprit is a local IEEE chapter with a few rogue members. But in general, in CS, you cannot go much wrong with ACM, IEEE, or Usenix as organizers. They will at least prevent conference papers for hire.

Comment: My downvote is for the first paragraph, which is misleading. The case of an unranked conference (which is the context of this question) significantly increases the probability that it could be a case of "things slipping by".

Comment: You might not have had experience with running IEEE conferences. They are not ideal, they make mistakes, but they have gotten more careful about new and old conferences.